# How can I conditionally, or contextually, load an interface of methods into a model from a Rails /lib?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, rails-activerecord

We have a set of reports that run out of `/lib`.  These have grown so voluminous that we now have written many methods that would count as helpers or other 'decorator-style' methods relating specifically to Reporting.

These additional methods live in the report, and look like:

```
class report
  def get_latest_credential_updated_date
    credentials.map(&:updated_at).compact.max
  end

  def initialize 
    # set up stuff
  end
end
```

1. Is there a way to load a module, or otherwise inject code to a Model when the reporting lib loads:

   ```
   class Loan < ActiveRecord::Base
     def get_latest_credential_updated_date
       credentials.map(&:updated_at).compact.max
     end
   end
   ```
2. Is there a better pattern to represent this architecture?

Comment: I couldn't understand the question.

Comment: @tamersalama I had made edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can create a "inject helper" with class_eval, something like:

```
def inject_to(class_name, &block)
  eval "#{class_name.name}.class_eval &block"
end

inject_to Loan do
 def get_latest_credential_updated_date
   credentials.map(&:updated_at).compact.max
 end
end
```

Comment: Yes, in the office we talked about using `class_eval`.  It feels extra-dirty, though